# Gorm w/ Postgres has a nested struct as JSON

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using GORM and I want to store the following struct in Postgres:

```golang
// Value GoDoc
type Value struct {
    Name  string
    Place string
    Value interface{}
}

// SharedConfig stores tenant-wide shared values
type SharedConfig struct {
    gorm.Model
    TenantID  string
    ProgramID *string
    Name      string
    Value     Value
}
```

I want to store SharedConfig in my DB and want the Value column to be stored as JSON, is this possible? I've only seen uses of the json column type as postgres.Jsonb

Comment: why not store it as jsonb? They're almost identical and jsonb (it's just a better binary representation, but that's just internals)